# Php - Multiply numbers in the string

Tags: php

Example
There is a variable (123.4234.1.3.)
I need explode this (.)
And multiply 123 4234 1 3

```
$formatted="123.4234.1.3.";
$parcalar = explode(".", $formatted);
foreach($parcalar as $element),
```

how can i continue

Comment: `$result = $result * $element;` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$formatted="123.4234.1.3.";
$numbers = explode(".", $formatted);
$mul = array_reduce($numbers, function ($carry, $value) {
    if ($value === "") { // skip empty values
        return $carry;
    }
    return $carry * $value;
}, 1);
var_dump($mul);
```

Output:

```
int(1562346)
```

`array_reduce` anyone? :D

Answer (score 3):

One liner!

Explode, remove blank items with [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and use array_product

```
$product = array_product(array_filter(explode(".", $formatted)));
```

Reference: [array_product](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php)

If need strict filter you can use the callback with strict comparison.

```
$product = array_product(array_filter(explode(".", $formatted), 
    function ($v){ return (int)$v !== 0; }));
```

Here is a [Demo](https://eval.in/524761)

Comment: Yaaaas one lineerrr!!. Does `array_filter` use loose comparison for it's values? (ie `"" == false` instead of `"" === false`). I don't see a `strict` parameter like `in_array` has.

Comment: cannot find anything mentioned about comparison method used in array_filter. but you can always use the callback function where you can use strict comparison.

Answer (score 0):

To multiply all numbers:

```
$total = 1;

foreach($parcalar as $element){
    $total *= $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the integer value of the string as follows:

```
$product= 1;
foreach($parcalar as $element){
    $product = $product * intval($element);
}
```

[intval Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Besides for a string as yours (`"12.4.1.3."`) which contains a dot at the end, the explode function would return an array as:

```
Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 4 [2] => 1 [3] => 3 [4] => )
```

The last value becomes 0.
So make sure the string doesn't end in a dot(.) unless that is what you want.

Comment: Technically you don't _need_ to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the caveman solution in case anyone is interested

```
$var = "123.12.2";
$tempstring = " ";
$count = 0;
$total = 1;
$length = strlen($var);
for($i=0;$i<=$length;$i++)
{
    if($var[$i]!='.' && $i!=$length)
    {
        $tempstring[$count] = $var[$i];
        $count++;
    }
    else//number ended, multiply and reset positions, clear temporary char array
    {
        $total *= intval($tempstring);
        $count=0;
        $tempstring = " ";
    }
}
echo $total;
```

will output `2952`